# Regex validation Not working

Tags: c#, regex

I use the Following Regex for Validate Input

**^[0-9 -]+$**

I need to Allow only plus,hyphen,space (+ - space).If i try to check the following string it doesn't match.

In the following string I use space,digit and +

```
1 2 2 2 2 2 +
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `+` inside the character class.

```
^[0-9 +-]+$
```